# How to quickly clean up unneccesary edges?

Tags: edges, metaballs

[image]

This is the result of converting a couple of metaballs into a mesh. I feel like extra edges on faces are gonna be a real pain while sculpting, so I was wondering if there's some way to make the process of cleaning up quicker.

Comment: You could use select edge loops or simply the Remesh tool (it will completely change the topology but as you are talking about sculpting...)

Comment: You could also use the decimate modifier, then a subdivision surface.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, we are not talking about "cleanup" here, but "remeshing".

You can of course do this (manually) in Blender, but if you want to do it automatically, Blender unfortunately has only limited tools to give you an acceptable result.

One possibility is to reduce the mesh or something similar. But it does not look good.

An algorithm can unfortunately never decide for you what is important to you. So you need a mechanism where you decide yourself what details are crucial for your object.

So the answer is: either remesh manually, or live with the artifacts of automated processing.

An alternative, if you consider a workaround via an external program as a solution and don't want to use ZBrush or similar, is [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes).

With this small tool you can quickly reshape your mesh and then edit it again in Blender.

Comment: thank you a lot! i'll try this